# Python: how to pass to a function which object member (possibly nested deeper down) to work on?

Tags: python, member

## Background

I have a dictionary of dictionaries of objects with list members x and y:

```
plot_data._trace_d = {
    TraceType.A: {
        'abc': TraceData(x=[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ], y=[10, 11, 12, 13])
        'def': TraceData(x=[100, 101, 102, 103], y=[110, 111, 112, 113])
    },
    TraceType.B: {
        'abc': TraceData(x=[1000, 1001, 1002], y=['x', 'y', 'z']),
        'def': TraceData(x=[1010, 1011, 1012], y=['xx', 'yy', 'zz'])
    }
}
```

I need to flatten each trace this in order to comply with my plotting tool (plotly), so that I have lists of the form:

```
# TraceType.A
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 102, 103]
y = [10, 11, 12, 13, 110, 111, 112, 113]
plot(x, y, ...)

# TraceType.B
x = [1000, 1001, 1002, 1010, 1011, 1012]
y = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz']
plot(x, y, ...)
```

## My current solution

Passing which member to flatten with, with a string.

```
class TraceData:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        x = []
        y = []
    # ...

class PlotData:
    def __init__(self):
        self._trace_d = {
            TraceType.A: TraceData(),
            TraceType.B: TraceData(),
        }
    # ...
    def flatten_trace_data(self, trace_type, dimension): # HERE! dimension is a string
        """For a trace type, get the lists for all nodes and concatenate them
        into a single list. Useful to build a single Plotly trace for multiple
        nodes."""
        flat_list = []
        for node, td in self._trace_d[trace_type].items():
            print("Flattening node %r dim %s" % (node, dimension))
            flat_list += getattr(td, dimension)

        return flat_list

plot_data = PlotData()
# ...
x = plot_data.flatten_trace_data(TraceType.A, 'x')
```

## What I want

It feels very dirty to give the dimension parameter as a string, it feels matlaby. Is there a way to tell a member function to do something on a given parameter of a member? Something like this:

```
x = plot_data.flatten_trace_data(TraceType.A, TraceData.x)
```

I've tried this, because why not, but `TraceData` has no attribute `'x'`.

What is an elegant way to tell the flattening function which dimension of the object (in a nested nested dict) along which to flatten?

Comment: Use `getattr` `setattr`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's still using a string, but definitely a good improvement. I'll update the code to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this with getattrib.

```py
def flatten_trace_data(self, trace_type, dimension):
"""For a trace type, get the lists for all nodes and concatenate them into a single list. Useful to build a single Plotly trace for multiple nodes."""
    flat_list = [] 
    for node, l in self._trace_d[trace_type].items():
        print("Flattening node %r dim %s" % (node, dimension))
        flat_list += getattr(l, dimension)
    return flat_list
```

## Edit 1, using property

```py
class PlotData: 
    def __init__(self): 
        self._trace_d = { 
           TraceType.A: TraceData(), 
           TraceType.B: TraceData(), } # ... 

    @property
    def x_A(self):
        flat_list = [] 
     for node, td in self._trace_d[TraceType.A].items():
         flat_list += td.x
      return flat_list
```

## Edit 2

What you want to acechive is something like this.

```py
plot_data = PlotData()
x = plot_data.A.x
y = plot_data.A.y
```

That will be the more pythonic way to this.

For that, you need to rethink each class from TaceData, TraceType and PlotData.

Comment: Funny I just edited my question with this change, after the comment I got from @juanpa.arrivillaga. But the argument to `flatten_trace_data` is still a string, I'm not sure it's very pythonese.

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, funny. From my knowledge, yes it's pytonic because this is the only way to do this with a function. However, you can create property in your PlotData class to get ride of string. I will update my awser.

Comment: If it's pythonic, then it is... I just saw that `getattr`  takes a string anyway. Note: typo on the first line of your answer, `getattrib` doesn't exist, it seems.

Comment: using property forces me to create n(TraceType) * n(dimensions) functions?

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, exactly. It's not really suitable, howerver you can imagine create a TraceD class.

Comment: I have a TraceData class, how do you mean? (it actually has 5 or 6 attributes , not only x and y)

Comment: Sorry that won't cut it I think. I could make the tracetypes (which are Enum) members of PlotData, but  _trace_d needs to be a dictionary since I don't know in advance their name or how many there could be.

Comment: @Gauthier So the pythonic way to do what you want is our first awnser  with getattrib, in this way no need to know how many Trace you have as you loop trought all of them,